# How to use Bytes from other assembly files and how to run another assembly file through the current running one

Tags: assembly, binary, operating-system, x86

Im Assembly language how can i accses defined bytes (db) in an external asm file?
For example:

::File 1::

```
;All it contains is bytes in this file
BytesIWant db 'Hello, World!$'
```

::File 2::

```
;In this file i want to print out the BytesIWant variable from File 1
mov ah, 09
mov dx, BytesIWant
int 21
```

Now how can i accomplish this task?
And I also have one more question.
How can i run another asm file from the host file.
Example:
::Host File::

```
;Random asm code goes here
{Here i want to start another asm program}
```

::Program To Start:: Ex. NextThing.bin

```
mov ah, 09
mov dx, hi
int 21

hi db 'Hello!$'
```

Comment: 1) Use a linker 2) depends on your OS API.

Comment: How do I use a linker? And the so is my own compeletly done in assembly

Comment: You seem to be writing a DOS program, so you should specify `-f obj` when you assemble, and then use TASM's `tlink` or MASM's `link` to link the object files into an executable.

Comment: Can that work with linking files as a binary?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand the question. It is about how to start another executable from a currently running executable, or it is a question how to link two objectfiles from the assembler together for to get only one executable file?

For to load and execute another executable within a running executable we can use the DOS "EXEC"-function with AH=4Bh and AL=1 of the int 21h with DS:DX pointing to the ASCIZ program name with extension and with ES:BX pointing to a parameter block. We have to save the addresses of our currently SS and SP registers in a memory location and after the child executable terminated, we have to load it back.

Example of a parameter block:

```
PARBLOCK  equ THIS WORD                ; Parameter-Block for the EXEC-Function
          DW 0                         ; same environment-block
          DW OFFSET COMLINE            ; Offset- and Segment- address
          DW SEG CODE                  ;  of the command line
          DD 0                         ; no data in PSP #1
          DD 0                         ; no data in PSP #2
COMLINE   DB 80h dup (0)               ; command line
```

Dirk

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but im running this off my own custom OS so it cannot use int 0x21 therefore i need another way to locate and execute the binary of the file.